# Can stopword list be dropped from TfidfVectorizer in interference

Tags: scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have quite a big text corpus and sklearn created 2mil of (infrequent) stopwords, do I need to store it to the disk, can I just drop the stop word list?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This question is not very clear to me

Comment: Can I set vectorizer.stopwords_ = [] before vectorizer.transform(X)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `stop_words` param as `None` if you want to drop the stop words from the vocabulary.

On the other hand, if you want to remove the less frequent words use `min_df` param in `TfidfVectorizer`.

Default value of `min_df` is 0, if you set the value as something like 0.2 or so, the size of vocabulary would greatly decrease.